# Best practice for storing DateTime values in Firebase with Unity3d

Tags: c#, datetime, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a Unity3d 2D game where I'm using Firebase as the database. I need to store quite a lot of `DateTime` values (as UTC) in the database and I'm wondering what the best practice is for doing this.

The `DateTime` fields will mainly be used for sorting/filtering.

According to the Firebase documentation, I should make use of the `Firebase.Database.ServerValues.TIMESTAMP` which is just an `object`

Thing is, I'm using strongly typed models for my Unity game, like so:

```
[Serializable]
public class Profile {

    [NonSerialized]
    public string ProfileKey;

    // Serializable attributes
    public string userId;
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string gender; // "M" or "F"
    public DateTime utcCreated; // UTC   
    public DateTime utcUpdated; // UTC
}
```

and when I save/update a `Profile` I'm using Unitys `JsonUtility.ToJson()` method, like this:

```
var profiles = db.Child ("profiles");

Profile profile = new Profile {
    userId = GameManager.Instance.User.UserId,
    name = "My new profile",
    age = 23,
    gender = "M",
    utcCreated = ?? // Should somehow use Firebase.Database.ServerValues.TIMESTAMP here, I guess?
};              

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (profile);     

var profileKey = profiles.Push ().Key;

profiles.Child (profileKey).SetRawJsonValueAsync (json, 1).ContinueWith (t => {
    // .. handle response here
});
```

I'm not sure what exactly I should set the `utcCreated` field to on my model. Tried to simply make the field an `object`, but no value was inserted into Firebase. Also tried to make it a string with a `.ToString()` to the `Firebase.Database.ServerValues.TIMESTAMP`object, but no value was inserted in Firebase.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? ;-) Or just any help/hint on best practices for storing dates and timestamps in Firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, for anyone else with this question who don't want to spend hours of hair-pulling frustration, the answer is: you cannot (and maybe should not, guess there's a reason for it) set the `ServerValue.Timestamp` object on your models/objects.

The `ServerValue.Timestamp` is something your specifically set on your Firebase documents by calling either `SetValueAsync()` or `UpdateChildrenAsync()`

So what I did, was adding two fields to my `Profile`class: one which represents the unix timestamp server value and one, which represents the unix timestamp server value as a C# `DateTime` object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
public class Profile
{

    [NonSerialized]
    public string profileKey;

    [NonSerialized]
    public long utcCreatedTimestamp;

    [NonSerialized]
    public DateTime utcCreated;

    // Serializable attributes
    public string userId;
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string gender; // "M" or "F"

    public Profile() { }

    public Profile(Dictionary<string, object> fromFirebaseResult)
    {
        userId = fromFirebaseResult.ContainsKey("userId") ? fromFirebaseResult.First(x => x.Key == "userId").Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        name = fromFirebaseResult.ContainsKey("name") ? fromFirebaseResult.First(x => x.Key == "name").Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        age = fromFirebaseResult.ContainsKey("age") ? int.Parse(fromFirebaseResult.First(x => x.Key == "age").Value.ToString()) : 0;
        gender = fromFirebaseResult.ContainsKey("gender") ? fromFirebaseResult.First(x => x.Key == "gender").Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

        if (fromFirebaseResult.ContainsKey("utcCreatedUnix")) {
            long milliseconds;
            if(long.TryParse(fromFirebaseResult.First(x => x.Key == "utcCreatedUnix").Value.ToString(), out milliseconds)) {
                utcCreatedTimestamp = milliseconds;

                DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

                utcCreated = epoch.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Profile` class has a default constructor and a constructor, which takes a `Dictionary<string, object>` since that's what we get from Firebase when querying it from Unity.

When saving a new `Profile` to Firebase, I create a new `Profile` object without setting anything related to the date and time. Save it in Firebase and then call `UpdateChildrenAsync` which sets the `utcCreatedUnix` field in Firebase. Like so:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

// Get the user id
string userId = GameManager.Instance.User.UserId;

// Get a reference to the profiles
var profiles = db.Child("profiles");

// Create a new serializable profile
Profile profile = new Profile {
    userId = userId,
    name = "Bo Mortensen",
    age = 34,
    gender = "M"
};              

// Serialize profile to JSON
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (profile);     

// Push a new document to the database
var profileKey = profiles.Push ().Key;

// Set JSON for this document
profiles.Child (profileKey).SetRawJsonValueAsync (json, 1).ContinueWith (t => {
    if (t.IsCompleted) {
        // Assign the profile key (unique key generated by Firebase) to the profile
        profile.profileKey = profileKey;

        // Set the Firebase server timestamp on the datetime object
        profiles.Child(profileKey).UpdateChildrenAsync(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "utcCreatedUnix", ServerValue.Timestamp } });
    }
});
```

And when getting a `Profile` document from Firebase, I can now do:

```
var db = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

var profileRef = db.Child("profiles/MyProfileKey");

profileRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var values = t.Result.Value as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;

    // Let the constructor populate the fields
    Profile profile = new Profile(values)
    {
        profileKey = profileRef.Key
    };


    DateTime createdDate = profile.utcCreated;
});
```

You might be asking why I'm not just storing  a `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` I could do that, but I don't want to rely on the clients clock settings. By using Firebases ServerValue.Timestamp, Firebase determines the correct time instead of the individual client using the app.

Hope this can be helpful to anyone else out there :-)